# Django Model Manager not cooperating

Tags: python, django, model

I have the following models setup:

```
class Link(models.Model):

    votes = LinkVoteManager()

class Vote(models.Model):

    voter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    link = models.ForeignKey(Link)
```

However; I can't get link.votes to display anything, it's just empty. Any ideas? I'm completely stuck.

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to get every link votes? this model definition is wrong.

Comment: change your model definition. your model structure is not suitable for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need custom Manager here for this purpose:

just do

```
class Link(models.Model):
   titlename = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Vote(models.Model):
   voter = models.ForeignKey(User)
   link = models.ForeignKey(Link, related_name="link_votes")
```

then to get the votes for a link do this:

```
{% for link in link_list %}
    {{link.titlename}}'s voters: 

    {# here, we are showing all voters for a given link: #}
    {% for vote in link.link_votes.all %}
       voter's name: {{ vote.voter.username }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```